# foreign language support for android platform

Tags: android, locale

I am parsing some data Using google web service. 
But when it comes to chinese language ,the problem is it returns something odd strings.

```
         e.g.   &#3757;&#20185;&#27004;&#22823;&#37202;&#24215;
```

how can i convert into proper chinese language????

Same problem for Japanese language too.

I use android 2.2 platform.

Comment: How are you decoding it?  Are you assuming a Big-5 or UTF-8?  Is there a content-type response header that provides a locale?

Comment: nope,, nothing like content type in response.i use json output.

Answer (score 0):

These odd characters are the HTML encoders, to parse or decode it you have to user `Html` class which provides `Html.fromHtml()` static method.

Try this below sample code to get desired output.

```
String str="&#3757;&#20185;&#27004;&#22823;&#37202;&#24215;";
String resultString= Html.fromHtml(str).toString();
Log.d("Testing",resultString);
```